# How to delete list inside nested list based on count?

Tags: python, list

```
import time

dc = []
def u():
    for i in range(10):
        if i < 5:
            dc.append([i])
    print(dc)

    time.sleep(10)

while True:
    u()
```

output after 1st run:`[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`

output after 2nd run:`[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`

output for 3rd run:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

output for 4th run:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

I want to delete the values from first iteration after 5 loops and keep the 2nd set of values until it reaches 5 loops.

How can I do this?

Comment: How would the output look on the 3rd or 4th run?

Comment: you are appending to a list. Each time you call `u` you are appending to `dc` which increases its size. Initialize the list INSIDE the function.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be tracking the length of each list inserted, and then removing that number.  Also your data makes no sense, since each item is also in it's own list, which is nonsensical.

```
x = [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
y = [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
dc = []
itemLengths = []

dc.extend(x)
itemLengths.append(len(x))
dc.extend(y)
itemLengths.append(len(y))
print(dc)
print(dc[itemLengths.pop(0):])
```

or a better way to handle this:

```
class U:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dc = []
        self.insertLength = []

    def add(self, data):
        self.dc.extend(data)
        self.insertLength.append(len(data))
        self.remove()
        return self

    def remove(self):
        if len(self.insertLength) == 6:
            self.dc = self.dc[self.insertLength.pop(0):]
        return self

    def wait(self, timer):
        time.sleep(10)

u = U()
u.add(x)
u.add(y)
u.add(x)
u.add(x)
u.add(x)
u.add(x)

print(u.insertLength)
print(len(u.insertLength))
print(u.dc)
```

Comment: actually i am trying to run a stock screener.
where data gets updated every  5 minutes. and gets scanned.
i wanted to prevent duplicate data.
to prevent duplicate data (signals) i'm appending data to a list.
however after a few runs the list is getting pretty long.
so i wanted to remove that data after 5 iterations.

[link](https://pastebin.com/ibSuQVzX)
have a look at this code.
i wanted to ask a simplified version. 
I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: ` import time

count = 0
dc = []
def u():
    for i in range(10):
        if i != 1:
            dc.append([count,i])
    time.sleep(10)
while True:
    count += 1
    zzz = ([item[0] for item in dc])
    print(zzz)
    if len(dc) != 0:
        my_a = dc[0][0]
        print('my_a:' ,my_a)
        print(count)
        if my_a + 5 == count:
            print('d')
            dc = [i for i in dc if i and (my_a not in i)]
            print(dc)

    u() `


does the job :)
Thanks a ton :)